# Control undo/redo move and resize

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm adding undo/redo functionality to my graphical editor, but I'm having some issues with undo/redo for move and resize.

The first thing is when I move my `Control` (`Ellipse` for example) and I click the undo button the `Ellipse` goes to another position than were it should go. When I press redo after the undo the `Ellipse` goes to the correct position.

Here is a link which will make it more clear what I mean: http://gyazo.com/d299fe5e52f08742e7fa2132f6ff9839

The second things which has a lot of agreements with the first thing is when I resize the `Control` (`Ellipse` for example) and I click undo the `Ellipse` has another size than it should have. After clicking redo again it has the right size again.

Here is a link which will make it more clear what I mean: http://gyazo.com/59ecdcba751ff3b8ffd053dd19cd9945

Maybe the problem is in the `MoveCommand` and `ResizeCommand` classes, my code is based on this code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33384/Multilevel-Undo-and-Redo-Implementation-in-Cshar. In the linked page they use `WPF` and `Thickness` is used for moving/resizing. In `WinForms` there's no `Thickness` but there's `Margin`/`Padding` which I also tried but with no luck. How to make the resizing / moving undo/redo work?

MoveCommand.cs

```
class MoveCommand : ICommand
{
    Control _control;
    int _changeOfTop;
    int _changeOfLeft;

    public MoveCommand(int top, int left, Control control)
    {
        _control = control;
        _changeOfTop = top;
        _changeOfLeft = left;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _control.Top = _control.Top + _changeOfTop;
        _control.Left = _control.Left + _changeOfLeft;
    }

    public void UnExecute()
    {
        _control.Top = _control.Top - _changeOfTop;
        _control.Left = _control.Left - _changeOfLeft;
    }

}
```

ResizeCommand.cs

```
class ResizeCommand : ICommand
{
    private int _changeOfWidth;
    private int _changeOfHeight;
    private Control _control;

    public ResizeCommand(int width, int height, Control control)
    {
        _changeOfWidth = width;
        _changeOfHeight = height;
        _control = control;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _control.Height = _control.Height + _changeOfHeight;
        _control.Width = _control.Width + _changeOfWidth;
    }

    public void UnExecute()
    {
        _control.Height = _control.Height - _changeOfHeight;
        _control.Width = _control.Width - _changeOfWidth;
    }
}
```

Ellipse.cs

```
class Ellipse : Control
{
    private Point mDown { get; set; }
    private Point conLoc { get; set; }
    private bool userResizing = false;
    private Form1 form =null;

    public Ellipse(Form1 form1)
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        this.form = form1;
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        // Draw a black ellipse in the rectangle represented by the control.
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, Width, Height);

    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        mDown = e.Location;
        conLoc = this.Location;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        if (this.Location != conLoc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You moved me");
            this.form.InsertInUnDoRedoForMove(conLoc.Y, conLoc.X, this);
        }

    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call MyBase.OnMouseMove to activate the delegate. 
        base.OnMouseMove(e);


        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Location = new Point(e.X + Left - mDown.X, e.Y + Top - mDown.Y);
        }
    }

    /* Allow resizing at the bottom right corner */
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {

        const int wmNcHitTest = 0x84;
        const int htBottomLeft = 16;
        const int htBottomRight = 17;
        const int WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x232;
        const int WM_NCLBUTTONDWN = 0xA1;

        if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDWN)
        {
            if (!userResizing)
            {
                userResizing = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Start Resizing");
                this.form.InsertInUnDoRedoForResize(this.Width, this.Height, this);
            }
        }
        else if (m.Msg == WM_EXITSIZEMOVE)
        {
            if (userResizing)
            {
                userResizing = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Finish Resizing");
            }
        }
        else if (m.Msg == wmNcHitTest)
        {
            int x = (int)(m.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF);
            int y = (int)((m.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
            Point pt = PointToClient(new Point(x, y));
            Size clientSize = ClientSize;
            if (pt.X >= clientSize.Width - 16 &&
                pt.Y >= clientSize.Height - 16 &&
                clientSize.Height >= 16)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)(IsMirrored ? htBottomLeft : htBottomRight);
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool draw;
    private int x, y, xe, ye;

    private Stack<ICommand> _Undocommands = new Stack<ICommand>();
    private Stack<ICommand> _Redocommands = new Stack<ICommand>();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        menuComboBoxShape.ComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Item));
    }

    public enum Item
    {
        Pencil,
        Rectangle,
        Ellipse,
    }


    private void panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        draw = true;
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;
    }

    private void panel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        draw = false;
        xe = e.X;
        ye = e.Y;

        Item item;
        Enum.TryParse<Item>(menuComboBoxShape.ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString(), out item);

        switch (item)
        {

            case Item.Pencil:
                using (Graphics g = panel.CreateGraphics())
                using (var pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black))     //Create the pen used to draw the line (using statement makes sure the pen is disposed)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(x, y), new Point(xe, ye));
                }
                break;
            case Item.Rectangle:
                var box = new Box(this);
                panel.Controls.Add(box);
                box.Location = new Point(x, y);
                box.Width = (xe - x);
                box.Height = (ye - y);
                //InsertCommand boxcmd = new InsertCommand(box, panel);
                InsertInUnDoRedoForInsert(box);
                break;
            case Item.Ellipse:
                var el = new Ellipse(this);
                panel.Controls.Add(el);
                el.Location = new Point(x, y);
                el.Width = (xe - x);
                el.Height = (ye - y);
                //InsertCommand elcmd = new InsertCommand(el,panel);
                InsertInUnDoRedoForInsert(el);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void undoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Undo(1);
    }

    private void redoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Redo(1);
    }

    private void clearAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        commandList.Clear();
        current = 0;
        panel.Controls.Clear();
    }

    public void Redo(int levels)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= levels; i++)
        {
            if (_Redocommands.Count != 0)
            {
                ICommand command = _Redocommands.Pop();
                command.Execute();
                _Undocommands.Push(command);
            }
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void Undo(int levels)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= levels; i++)
        {
            if (_Undocommands.Count != 0)
            {
                ICommand command = _Undocommands.Pop();
                command.UnExecute();
                _Redocommands.Push(command);
            }
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    #region UndoHelperFunctions
    public void InsertInUnDoRedoForInsert(Control control)
    {
        ICommand cmd = new InsertCommand(control, panel,shapeTreeView);
        _Undocommands.Push(cmd); _Redocommands.Clear();
    }

    public void InsertInUnDoRedoForResize
    (int width, int height, Control control)
    {
        ICommand cmd = new ResizeCommand(width, height, control);
        _Undocommands.Push(cmd); _Redocommands.Clear();
    }

    public void InsertInUnDoRedoForMove
    (int top, int left, Control control)
    {
        ICommand cmd = new MoveCommand(top,left,control);
        _Undocommands.Push(cmd); _Redocommands.Clear();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: It looks like your undo/redo are expecting to save a delta in the position but when you pass in values you are passing in an absolute position instead. This would be why undo is wrong but redo isn't. Undo is using this absolute value as a delta value but redo works fine because it gets the same absolute value and thus the same delta that undo did.

Comment: @JarrettRobertson How to fix my code?

Comment: In your elipse you could try changing OnMouseUp from this.form.InsertInUnDoRedoForMove(conLoc.Y, conLoc.X, this); to this.form.InsertInUnDoRedoForMove(conLoc.Y - this.Location.Y, conLoc.X - this.Location.X, this); This would give you the delta between where you started and where you ended. This would prove out what I think your problem is. I'll note however I wouldn't implement undo/redo this way at all and would take a look at the memento pattern.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution doesn't work, and about the pattern the requirement is to use the command pattern. This is the result of your solution: http://gyazo.com/bfae2e48071f633ca2f12a8309a8fbc6

Comment: When you debug the old/new positions what does it say? create it get the position move it get the position then undo and get the position. And I take it this is an assignment of some sort?

Comment: What do you mean by what does it say? And what do you mean with this: create it get the position move it get the position then undo and get the position ? And it's my assignment to create a graphical editor with some patterns where command pattern is one pattern.

Comment: It being the values in the IDE. The create it means create an ellipse use the debugger to get its position and move it to see what the debugger is telling you.

Comment: Here's an example : I create an `Ellipse` with `conLoc x: 162` and `conLoc y: 96`, I move the `Ellipse` to `Control.Left : 355` and `Control.Top: 99`, `_changeOfTop is 96` and `changeOfLeft is 162` this makes a new `Control.Top` of 3 in `UnExecute` which is part of the problem I think, how to solve it?

Comment: That looks right, your ellipse moved 3 from 96 to 99 so subtract 3 from its current position to get the old position.

Comment: But  with the values from above in `UnExecute`  `_control.Top = _control.Top - _changeOfTop;` the new `_control.Top` = `99-96=3` but it has to be `96` instead of `3` right?

Comment: Yes so that is your issue, where your unexecute is doing math on a delta position but what is being passed into unexecute is an absolute position. You need 3 to be passed in OR you need to not do the math for a delta position and just restore the position that is being passed in.

Comment: If i restore the passed in position I lose the unlimited undo/redo functionality after undo I can't redo anymore.

Comment: When you undo a command you just create a new redo command and put it onto your redo list.

Comment: That's what I'm doing in `undo(int levels)`

Comment: There is way too much code in your example. It seems certain that the problem could be reproduced without much of it. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I already fixed the problems myself, and did you vote to close it?